# change color of the text on the indented tree - d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

i wanna change the color of my text everywere on the indented tree, i already tried to add something like this :

```
style="color: white"
```

But this doesn't work, so how can i do it ? thank you guys

Link of the code and preview of the idented tree : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
.style('fill', 'darkOrange')
```